# Anyone know of a flexible Metro ui for winforms?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, layout, microsoft-metro

A lot of them have hard coded square small and 2 squares sized large tiles.  I am looking for something flexible enough for at least the size ratio to be adjustable to be more flat.

Telerik has a flexible approach (you can choose any row and column span for a tile) but their implementation is either laughably primitive is still too new, especially the drag and drop part.

Devexpress has nice drag and drop, but is stuck doing 1x1 and 1x2 sized tiles.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I believe DevEpress are using those sizes to stay inside of the "touch-screen" parameters...have you contacted their support?

Comment: You might find helpful info here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465326 and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DevComponents](http://www.devcomponents.com/dotnetbar/metro-ui-controls.aspx) is my favorite. With WPF, you can copy most of the XAML you would otherwise use in a Metro application - so don't feel that you can't emulate Metro on the desktop. Many have already done it. Certainly, many more will.

But there are some downsides to Desktop development. Although desktop development is very powerful, and it is, Metro development in Windows 8 has [considerable advantages](http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2012/05/windows-8-top-10-reasons-why-metro.html). Having said that, desktop development can take advantage of Visual Studio 11, too.

Comment: I am currently getting into WPF + XAML + C# code behind and some more elaborate stuff further down the chain in the Model. It already feels much better than the contortions of Winforms. I like where MS is going with the store apps, but until they can live in a resizeable window on the desktop they are just unusable for my common use case (desktop) and target environment (Win7).

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the [Devcomponents DotNetBar](http://www.devcomponents.com/dotnetbar/). It has pretty flexible Metro tiles.

Comment: I do not see any drag and drop rearranging for them?  Are they all statically located?

Comment: Nope, drag and drop is supported

Answer (score 0):

metro-ui should be used with WPF and that will work great there too.
If you want to implement Metro-UI in windows from you have to create your own user control.

Comment: My problem is I am using VSTO.  All of their code examples and help are C# and VB.