# Winform custom GridLayout?

Tags: c#, winforms, grid-layout

I am trying to make a `GridLayout` for my form. Each cell needs to contain an image and label underneath describing the picture.

I was wondering what was the best way to attack this issue?

Comment: On a second thought, it looks like in your windows application you are trying to develop a metro layout, now called Windows 8 Style. There is no need to recreate the wheel, and better use [existing solutions from 3rd party](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9765111/anyone-know-of-a-flexible-metro-ui-for-winforms). You'll save time along the way. By googling I also found [this for 21 CDN per developer](http://www.pfgrid.com/Metro_UI_Tiles_WinForms.aspx) - no idea how good or bad it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a [TableLayoutPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.aspx) control to your form. Create as many rows and columns as you need. Because each cell can only contain one control, and you need two, add a [SplitContainer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0w5ctby.aspx) control into each cell - now you can have two controls per cell. Set its [SplitContainer.Orientation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.splitcontainer.orientation.aspx) = Horizontal. Resize splitter to whichever split applies to your situation. Set [SplitContainer.IsSplitterFixed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.splitcontainer.issplitterfixed.aspx) = True.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on Neolisk's answer, instead of using a Split Container, make a separate User Control. Put a PictureBox and Label on there. Do what you need to do to display the information in the Load method of the Control.

Then just add the Control to each TableLayoutPanel.

That will keep everything separated.

Comment: +1. Yeah, this would be better for re-usability, of course.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [TableLayoutPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.aspx).